# Update the DOM with new data after async operation angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I have the following scenario, in my view component I have an input field, in this fieldI am placing a URL and then clicking a button which starts an async call to my backend, when the data returned everything is updated properly.the returned data is json object which contain array of image links.

Input Component:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin: 10px">
  <div class="panel-body">
<div class="input-group" >
        <input 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="import link" 
            #input >
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button 
            class="btn btn-warning" 
            type="button" 
            (click)="onGetUserTitle(input)"
            >Go!</button>
      </span>
      </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Form Component:

```
      <h4>Item Images</h4>
  <div class="images">
    <img #imagesArray 
         *ngFor="let imgSrc of images" 
         src={{imgSrc}} 
         width="112" 
         height="106" 
         style="margin: 5px" >
  </div>
```

The issue starts when in the exact same page I am replacing the existing URL in the input field with a new one and starting a new async operation. the data is returned however the images in the page stay the same and not getting updated with the new set of links returned from the backend.

So the main question can I cause the images to be update with new src links arrive from the response? I tried working with subjects/zones and also looked at several SO Q&A but wasnt able to find the solution.

Comment: Did you try with `[src]="imgSrc"`

Comment: Tried it now and it does not have any affect

Comment: are you sure images is getting updated . what does `{{images | json}} ` print

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I am logging the json data in the server response and I can see that the data changes

Comment: Can you show the code that updates the images array?

Comment: Well I am not sure how but now it seems to work with your initial proposal. could you explain why making this change resolved the issue?

Comment: @user2145673 - the square brackets bind the data to the html property so that it can be used in the view. Look at : http://lishman.io/angular-2-property-binding